# RSelenium Code Improvement: Stale Element Reference

Tags: html, r, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm using RSelenium in for a loop in R and would like to reduce the number of lines of code that I'm using. When I explicitly call out the xpath in each loop, it works, but if I try storing the xpath and calling it again, I get "Selenium message:stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

This code **does not** work:

```
test1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/img')  
test2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/img')  
test3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/img') 

while(2 > 1) {
  test1$clickElement()
  test2$clickElement()
  test3$clickElement()
}
```

But this code **does** work:

```
while(2 > 1) {
  test1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/img')   
  test1$clickElement()
  test2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/img')   
  test2$clickElement()
  test3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/img')   
  test3$clickElement()
}
```

Why do I have to call the xpath everytime before it clicks? It's adding many more lines of code to my script as I have to do this for more than just three tests. I would rather just store the xpath at the start of my script and call upon it in my loop. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say without a reproducible example. What happens when you click the element? Does it change the HTML content? Perhaps it replace or creates the values you are trying to select and find in subsequent steps.

Comment: When the element is clicked, the page refreshes.

Comment: If the page refreshes, then all existing elements disappear and new ones are created. When you run `findElement`, it searches the current page with the xpath expression. If the page changes, then the element you previously found likely no longer exists on the page. You can't click it any more. It's been deleted. So you need to find the element you want to click on the current page.